# Reference cell range on another sheet - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, range

I have 3 sheets, say they're "sheet1", "sheet2" and "datasheet". On "sheet2" have "$A$3" in cell B3 (this is dynamically generated), and on "sheet1" I want to create a function (eg sum or average) based on data from "datasheet" using $A$3 as the starting row until the last row. How would I do this? There's too many nesting functions I'm continuously getting parse errors:

```
=SUM('datasheet'!INDIRECT('sheet2'!B3 & ":" & 'datasheet'!A))
```

Basically, in terms of pseudo-code:

```
=SUM(datasheet[cell ID written on B3 of "sheet2"]:[last row of "datasheet"])
```

Comment: Will the column change or is it always `A`

Comment: Column is always A on datasheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column is static, always A, then in B3 on sheet2 just put the starting row number and use this formula:

```
=SUM(INDEX('datasheet'!A:A,Sheet2!$B$3):INDEX('datasheet'!A:A,MATCH(1E+99,'datasheet'!A:A)))
```

It will sum from the row indicated to the last cell with a number in it.

---

Another option as SUM will ignore any non numeric values the formula can be shortened to:

```
=SUM(INDEX('datasheet'!A:A,Sheet2!$B$3):'datasheet'!A65000)
```

Change the 65000 to a ridiculously large number that will never be reached in your dataset.